# WHMCS URL-friendly Custom created page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, whmcs

I need to load WHMCS [custom page](https://developers.whmcs.com/advanced/creating-pages/) without .php extension but it returns 404.
URL friendly rules are set on htaccess as [default](https://docs.whmcs.com/Friendly_URLs#WHMCS_Rules).
but they only apply for basic pages.
the last solution would be to set custom rules on htaccess for specific URLs to load without the .php extension.

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: how to load WHMCS custom page without .php extension, or how to define a rule for specific page on htaccess to load without .php extension.

Comment: OK, then please add your current implementation to the question so that it can be checked.

Comment: the code was the same as the provided default link, there was no need to add it to the question. however, I ended up setting specific rules for all of the custom pages in htaccess file as the following:  RewriteRule ^customPage$ customPage.php [L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up setting custom rules on htaccess for each custom page to also load without the .php extension.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#rempove .php for custom pages on by one
RewriteRule ^customPageOne$ customPageOne.php [L]
RewriteRule ^customPageTwo$ customPageTwo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^customPageThree$ customPageThree.php [L]

# Redirect directories to an address with slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$  $1/ [R]

# Send all remaining (routable paths) through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Determine and use the actual base
RewriteCond $0#%{REQUEST_URI} ([^#]*)#(.*)\1$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %2index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```